# Seeking references on the geometry of regular four-dimensional polytopes

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I've got intrested in the geometry of higher dimensional spaces. Now I'm studying four dimensional geometry. I'm especially interested in regular four dimensional polytopes and their visalization. I've found some intresting information [here](http://eusebeia.dyndns.org/4d/vis/vis) and [here](https://hollasch.github.io/ray4/Four-Space_Visualization_of_4D_Objects.html#fig3.4).

I am trying to find some literature focused on the geometry of the polytopes itself but not on the visalization only. Has someone been interested in the topic? What literature can you advice me to read?

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to take a look at "Kaleidoscopes: Selected Writings of H.S.M. Coxeter" by F. Arthur Sherk, Peter McMullen, Anthony C. Thompson and Asia Ivic Weiss. Also you can check "Introduction to Geometry" by H.S.M. Coxeter (there is a chapter about four-dimensional geometry at the very end of the book). And there is also a paper called "Regular and semi-regular polytopes" by Irene POLO-BLANCO in which one can find a brief description of regular four-dimensional polytopes and some methods of studying them.

Answer (score 1):

The standard reference work is still Coxeter's *Regular Polytopes* (e.g. Dover edition).

He discusses the two-, three- and four-dimensional examples in some detail, as well as the few which have analogues in higher dimensions still.

He also includes useful background remarks, especially historical detail, and photos of some nice wireframe models made by another investigator.

However, if your interest arises more from their fourth dimension than their regularity, then this is not the best resource. There are innumerable uniform polytopes of four dimensions (A project existed in recent years to enumerate them all, I am not sure if it has succeeded yet) and even more with lower symmetries.